# Android:cannot make a selection after WebView search with highlight

Tags: android, webview, selection, clipboard, highlight

Hello I have a bug in my app and I cannot figure it out.

I want to search for text in my WebView and get the found Text highlighted

for Android 1.5-2.3 this works quite well

```
public void onClick(View v){  
        webView1.findNext(true);

        int i = webView1.findAll(findBox.getText().toString()); 

        try{  
        Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);  
        m.invoke(webView1, true);  
        }catch(Exception ignored){}  
        } 
}
```

for Android 3.0+ I have to use the JavaScript workaround from [here](http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm), because Google doesn't support the highlighting of searched text for incomprehensible reasons

And now my Bug: After the search on my WebView I get the highlighted Text, and I can't select the Text anymore. The only fix I could use is the JavaScript workaround in older Android versions, too. But the function runs very slow and it takes about 10 seconds until the text gets highlighted. I Hope someone has a better solution/fix :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have found a quite good solution.

Here is a JavaScript code for Highlighting, that runs really fast :) http://4umi.com/web/javascript/hilite.php#thescript

Anyway I don't understand, why I can't selecting text after the of the official Webview search

Answer (score 1):

I use the same for 3.x then it did not work on 4.0.x.
Yesterday I updated to 4.0.4 and now highlight works again.

So the solution can be found in the 4.0.4 sources.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 3.x I used webview.showFindDialog(stringtofind, true);

Answer (score 0):

use findAllAsync() instead , finAll() is deprecated in API 16;